# Dynamically select a section to be editable in a table

Tags: ios, swift

On my `UITableView`, I have two sections. Each section has an "edit" button. The user should be able to edit either section (re-order rows or delete a row).

**Question**

I have implemented the following function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if (indexPath.section == 1 || indexPath.section == 2) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

However, when one of the "edit" buttons is pressed, both sections will become editable at the same time (delete and move buttons shown). How to make sure only one of them becomes editable? I have done some researches yet not very helpful. Sorry if this question is dumb. Any help will be really appreciated. (I am very new to Swift) Thanks in advance.

**Some thoughts**

I am thinking to add the "tag" info to each button. And when the button is pressed, the tag info is passed to `@IBAction func editButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)`. However, how should I then pass this info to the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function and return the correct boolean variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property to track which section you are editing.  You can set the property either using the edit button `tag` or by having separate `@IBAction` functions.  Either way, you can then check the property in `canEditRowAt`.

By the way, if you only have two sections in your table, they will be numbered 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

```
var editingSection: Int?

@IBAction func editButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.editingSection = sender.tag
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    guard let editingSection = self.editingSection else {
        return false
    }

    return indexPath.section == editingSection
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it! Yep. I have more than 2 sections.

Comment: Ok, then you will need to adjust my code slightly to prevent editing of other sections, but I am sure you get the idea

Comment: Yep. Really straightforward. I didn't know why I got stuck for a long time. Thanks again.